# CSS Grid Landing Page/Single Image

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to take a single image and centre it using CSS grid, both as a way to teach myself grid and because my page calls for a single, centred image. The image is centring left-to-right but not top-to-bottom. It sits right at the top. I made the image smaller to make viewing it for test purposes easier. The size of my image is less important than its placement. What am I doing wrong?

Also, I want this in a 3x3 grid, not some other number value.

```css
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.ConstructGrid {
    justify-items: center;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 1px;
    grid-template-areas: ". . ." ". picture ." ". . .";
}
```

```html
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="ConstructGrid">
                <img class="picture" src="http://www.cafenocturne.com/images/Under_Construction.png" border="0" width="400">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier than you think.
the container should be the grid, within you can set the child in its area/cell.
an height or min-height is also required even if 1fr would manage some height

```css
body {
margin:0;
}
.wrapper {/* i draw the grid , i'm the boss !*/
  height: 100vh;/* let me lay from top to bottom. I'm the boss, i want it whole  */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1px;
  grid-template-areas: ". . ." ". picture ." ". . .";
}

.ConstructGrid {
  grid-area: picture;/* tell me where to be, i'm the prisoner */
  margin:auto;/* let me be in the center of my area/cell  :) */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="ConstructGrid">
    <img class="picture" src="http://www.cafenocturne.com/images/Under_Construction.png" border="0" width="400">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use the grid. Because you didn't set `display:grid` for `.ConstructGrid`. You can use only flexbox to center the image. Also you should set `height: 100%` to center it vertically.

```css
html,
body,
.wrapper,
.ConstructGrid {
  height: 100%;
}

.ConstructGrid {
  display: flex; /* this can be display: grid also */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="ConstructGrid">
    <img class="picture" src="http://www.cafenocturne.com/images/Under_Construction.png" border="0" width="400">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Uh... How do I learn grid if you, um, take out the grid code? I want to do this in grid, *specifically*, not in flexbox. Thanks anyway.

Comment: you didn't use `grid-template-rows/columns/areas`

Comment: But my wrapper has "display: grid". Does this mean I have to include "display: grid" in all child divs? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You have to use the grid properties on the element that has the `display: grid` property. Not on their childs.

Comment: I literally have grid-template-rows etc. in my code. It's *right there*. I'm confused now.

Answer (score 1):

You should't have both display grid and display flex at the same block of code, otherwise, it will overwritten by the other.
In your code you have display:flex just below of display grid.

Display grid will apply when you remove display flex within .wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it like that to reserve the centered Area for the image. I use .picture-container as the wrap-element for the Image and use responsive widths and heights to get it centered right. Flex is only used inside the Wrap-Element for the Image so it doesnt interfere with the Css-Grid:

```css
body{
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .wrapper {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            display: grid;
            justify-items: center;
            grid-template-rows: auto;
            grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
            grid-template-areas:
                    ". . . ."
                    " . image image ."
                    ". . . .";
        }
        .picture-container{
            grid-area: image;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="picture-container">
            <img class="picture" src="http://www.cafenocturne.com/images/Under_Construction.png" border="0">
        </div>
</div>
```

I also always prefer to set a height and width for your whole Area in cases like this, thats why i added them to the body. That makes it way easier to position Elements.

Comment: I thought grid could be so much simpler than this? Why is it touted as so simple and great that it needs all this extra? I also wanted a 3x3 grid, not 4. Thank you for your try at helping me but this isn't anything like I asked for. I'm sorry to have troubled you.

Comment: ah i just used a random layout as an example. It's basically the same with any grid layout, you chose the correct answer for your problem, i just wanted to give an example of the basic idea behind the layout in grid

Comment: this looks like too big

Comment: what do you mean too big? its basically the same as the accepted answer just with an alternative way of centering the image and 1 more column which doesnt matter as its just an example how grid and Flex can be combined. Its not even much more code